# Bitbucket pipeline maven cache is not caching all artifacts

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I am using maven cache in my pipeline and I have a question. In my settings.xml I define my privet Jfrog repository for lib_release and lib_snapshot.

```
definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &compile
        name: compile
        caches:
          - maven
        script:
          - mvn -s settings.xml clean compile package
        artifacts:
          - target/**

I see that in Build stage artifacts are Downloaded from the maven cache:

>Cache "maven": Downloading.  
>Cache "maven": Downloaded 103.5 MiB in 4 seconds.  
>Cache "maven": Extracting.  
>Cache "maven": Extracted in 1 seconds

But during the build I see that some .pom, maven-metadata.xml, and some .jar files still downloading from my privet Jfrog artifactory.

For example:
>Downloaded from snapshots: https://jfrog.com/libs-snapshot/my-data/1.5.1-SNAPSHOT/my-data--1.pom (6.3 kB at 8.7 kB/s) 


*So the question is why this data is not cashed?*
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a snapshot. Snapshots are always retrieved to make sure the build has the latest version of it. Only the server knows the latest version of a snapshot (You can do an `mvn clean install` and look at your local repository to see the generated pom how this works).

https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#What_is_a_SNAPSHOT_version